# AWS S3 SDK ListObjectsV2 what's difference between startafter and ContinuationToken?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm using `Aws::S3::Model::ListObjectsV2Request` to list objects in AWS s3.

(It's c++ sdk, but I suppose the implementation is the same with Java, so if you're familiar with Java AWS S3 sdk pls also take a look at my question)

There're more than 1000 objects so can not fit in one page according to SDK 1000 records limit.

I found two API seems both reasonable to deal with this issue.
1.

```
// pseudo code
list_req
all_res = []
while true {
    res = list_req.request()
    all_res.add(res.get_all_entries())
    if (res.isTruncated()) {
        list_req.set_continuation_token(res.get_continuation_token());
    }
}
```

2.

```
// pseudo code
list_req
all_res = []
while true {
    res = list_req.request()
    all_res.add(res.get_all_entries())
    if (res.isTruncated()) {
        list_req.set_start_after(res.get_last_entry());
    }
}
```

What's the difference between these two approaches? (My situation is that I will get an exception with first approach `The continuation token provided is incorrect with address : 52.218.217.49`, so I can only use the second one.)

Comment: The continuation token is tied to a particular client session, whereas start after can be used by any client and never expires.

Comment: If you can provide your actual code for #1, we could attempt to reproduce your situation.

Comment: For the error: `The continuation token provided is incorrect`, kindly refer to https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=256859

The continuation token, being Base64, often includes "=, +, or /" characters. If the authentication code includes a plus (+) sign, encode it as %2B in the request. Encode a forward slash as %2F and equals as %3D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **StartAfter** (string) -- StartAfter is where you want Amazon S3 to start listing from. Amazon S3 starts listing after this specified key. StartAfter can be any key in the bucket.
>
> **ContinuationToken** (string) -- ContinuationToken indicates Amazon S3 that the list is being continued on this bucket with a token. ContinuationToken is obfuscated and is not a real key.

So, if you want to start listing a bucket from objects that begin with `G`, then use `StartAfter = 'G'`.

The `ContinuationToken` is used when more than 1000 results were returned. In such a case, the response provides a `ContinuationToken` that you must pass into the next call. The results will continue from where the last listing finished.

You can specify both of the parameters, if wanting to start at a particular name and retrieve more than 1000 objects.

Comment: if `maxKeys` is given in the request then `ContinuationToken` is used when more than `maxKeys` results were returned.... by default `maxKeys` is 1000